# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8046 when connecting to host app from Docker container - Windows 10

Tags: docker, containers, localhost

I have a standalone app running on my machine (not in a docker container) listening to port 8046 (localhost:8046) using an ngrok tunnel (http ngrok 8046). I am trying to connect to it sending a POST from my docker container which I'm also running on my local machine using http://host.docker.internal:8046. I have tried many different approaches but nothing seems to work:

- I have tried to disable my firewall to make sure that wasn't the issue.
- Tried http://localhost:8046 in the container to connect to the app
- Tried serving the standalone app on 0.0.0.0 with the same port 8046 and setting http://0.0.0.0:8046 in the container to connect to it, unsuccessfully

I keep having connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8046

my etc/hosts is configured with the IP added by docker desktop for host.docker.internal and gateway.docker.internal

I'm running out of ideas and can't figure out what I could be missing. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Inside container `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `0.0.0.0` represent the container itself. To connect to the host machine please try using its domain name or IP address in the LAN, which the host machine belongs to.

Comment: You're right, it worked! That´s because Windows machines, as well as Mac, containers are inside a VM, so the container's host is actually the VM and not my machine... Thanks a lot!